# Need a bit of php/mysql handholding here: does wordpress post exist before import

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress install and am trying to see if a post already exists before I import it from a CSV

If I use phpmyadmin, the following search is 100% true and yields 2 accurate results:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE 'the quick brown fox'
```

Then when I Select the "create php" link, I get this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE \'the quick brown fox\'";
```

I then create import.php and save it with this:

```
<?php
include '/path/to/wp-blog-header.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE \'the quick brown fox\'";
$existingPost = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$existingPost) {
    echo "post does not exist. Running insertFromCSV.php";
    include "insertFromCSV.php"; //defined elsewhere and 100% working
    }
else {
    echo "you already have this in your database";
    }
?>
```

The issue is that when I run import.php, the result is "post does not exist. Running insertFromCSV.php" which is NOT true. The post title DOES in fact exist.

Where am I going wrong here? Where is my human error? :)

I appreciate any thoughts on this and thanks in advance...

Comment: Try with the backslashes around `\'the quick brown fix\'` removed - you don't need them if you're using double quotes to define the variable.

Comment: Was just thinking the same thing - no need to escape them. Otherwise looks like it should work.

Comment: This solution worked. Its greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP site:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

So the first problem is that mysql_query doesn't do what you want. It returns a resource, which you can use to fetch the result. In your case it doesn't return a resource, thus there is some error.

To see if the amount of posts returned from your query, you need to use mysql_num_rows:

```
 $res = mysql_query(..);
 $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Further more:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE \'the quick brown fox\'";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_title` LIKE 'the quick brown fox'";
```

And if you want the actual posts:

```
 $res = mysql_query(...);
 $posts = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

And better use PDO or some other abstraction layer instead of the mysql_* functions. They have a lot of handy features.

Comment: +1 on PDO, but if all he wants is to see whether result is false, no need to do anything else...

Comment: @KristenJukowski As I understood it, he wants to know the post is there or not. But now he is essentially testing his connection and whether he typed the query correctly. mysql_query returns a resource, which needs to be queried with mysql_num_rows to see if there are posts.

Comment: Very much appreciated. I literally copied the php created from the phpmyadmin result which included the esc slashes...I didnt know that I didnt need the actual slashes when I cutCopyPasted into my php file.

Worked like a charm and thanks for your time/efforts! - EM

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to escape `'` in your query when you are surrounding the php string with `"`